# Internal Server Error using apache django mod_wsgi or 500 internal server error mod_wsgi apache

Tags: django, apache, deployment, mod-wsgi

wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gis_api.settings')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

httpd.conf

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:81
LoadFile "C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python310.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/lib/site-packages/"
<VirtualHost *:81>
    WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/django_project/gis_api/gis_api/gis_api/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "D:/django_project/gis_api/gis_api/gis_api/">    
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "D:/django_project/gis_api/gis_api/static/"
    <Directory "D:/django_project/gis_api/gis_api/static/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    Alias /media "D:/django_project/gis_api/gis_api/media/"
    <Directory "D:/django_project/gis_api/gis_api/media/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

error.log

- mod_wsgi (pid=20212): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/django_project/gis_api/gis_api/gis_api/wsgi.py'., referer: http://127.0.0.1:81/
- mod_wsgi (pid=20212): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/django_project/gis_api/gis_api/gis_api/wsgi.py'., referer: http://127.0.0.1:81/
- Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://127.0.0.1:81/
- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gis_api'\r, referer: http://127.0.0.1:81/

version :

- Django                   4.1.1
- mod-wsgi                 4.9.4
- os window 10

I have try to all solution. But getting error. I am beginner to deployment in django apache. Pl guide me best path of deployment.

my project structure
[image]

Comment: Your apache server config looks strange. You might move try moving the WSGI settings inside the <virtualhost> tags and also using WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup

Comment: @GracenOwnby  i am using window10 os.  
this note is mod_wsgi official documentation.
1) Note that the WSGIDaemonProcess directive and corresponding features are not available on Windows.
2) Note that the WSGIProcessGroup directive and corresponding features are not available on Windows or when running Apache 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

WSGIPythonPath needs to point to your app directory like

```
WSGIPythonPath "D:/django_project/gis_api"
```

For the moment you are twice adding the environment path (WSGIPythonHome and ...Path) to the python search path but not your apps directory.